# Python code works except when run from automator

Tags: python, selenium, automator

I have a Python Selenium script I am using to automatically connect to a specific public WiFi, the code works from my IDE as well as when the script is run with the shell executable I created for it, but if i try to run that executable from automator it throws an error. The specific line I'm having issues with is this:

```
PID2close=check_output(["pidof","Captive Network"])
```

It throws "File not Found." Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Welcome to SO. I'd try throwing in a `print(os.getcwd())` before the problematic statement because I guess that automator is running your script in a different working directory and thusly does not find the file.

Comment: can you do a print(os.environ) before this call and check that pidof is in the path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I abandoned depending on the "pidof" function and instead used

```
os.system("sudo pkill -f Captive Network Assistant")
```

This way, the code now only depends on Mac's native terminal commands, and you can entirely avoid the whole issue I was having. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a os.chdir(PATH_WITH_FILE) at the beginning of the script.

Comment: This didn’t seem to fix it, although now my prints are going to the same file, so that may have been an issue as well.

Comment: That'd be a separate issue I think, would probably require to see more of the code.